# Error in importing module of python library scipy

Tags: python, distance, scipy-spatial

I am working on clustering in python. The package I want to import is

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import dist
```

but this is showing the following error.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'dist' from 'scipy.spatial.distance' (C:\Users\majid\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py)

Comment: `import scipy.spatial.distance as dist`

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy-spatial-distance-cdist)?

Comment: yes it is dist as for as i know

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing dist you need to import pdist or cdist based on your requirement as per the SciPy documentation:

pdist(X[, metric])

Pairwise distances between observations in n-dimensional space.

cdist(XA, XB[, metric])

Compute distance between each pair of the two collections of inputs.